# Change multiple glyphicons with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, glyphicons

I am using Bootstrap glyphicons as checkboxes for multiple nodes on a folder tree.  I need to toggle all glyphicon checkboxes for a given folder (but ONLY THIS folder and ONLY CHECKBOXES) when said folder's checkbox is clicked.

```
<li data-layerid="Analises" data-grouped="group_Analises" class="parent_li">
  <span title="Collapse this branch"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> Analises</span>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" id="group_Analises" data-foldername="group_Analises"></i></li>

<li data-layerid="V%" data-grouped="2014">
  <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file glyphicon-check"></i> V%</span>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" id="2014" data-foldername="2014"></i> 
</li>
<li data-layerid="Ca" data-grouped="2014">
  <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file glyphicon-check"></i> Ca</span>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" id="2014" data-foldername="2014"></i> 
</li>
```

If I do this, I change all glyphicons on the page.

```
$('i').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
```

[image]

If I attempt to access the id directly, I only manage to change the first element with this id, not all of them:

```
$('#2014').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
```

[image]

Suggestions VERY welcome.

Comment: I recommend you to not use `id` attribute for multiple tag, use class instead..

Comment: Just to inform. ID - unique. It's prohibited to use few same ID in one page. It would be the same if someone had passport number as yours.

Comment: @guradio tried but it didnt work.

Comment: Is 2014 the id of ul or ol ? Can you add all relevant code

Comment: @ukasyah tks, but class is always `glyphicon` for all elements that use them.  so, the result ends up being the same...

Comment: @guradio `2014` is the id of the `<i>` tag(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove id attribute on DOM, use `data-foldername` attribute instead.

```
$('i[data-foldername="2014"]').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
```